# Is science based on David Hume's "A wise man, therefore, proportions his belief to the evidence"?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, hume, scientific-method

> "A wise man, therefore, proportions his belief to the evidence. … no
>   testimony is sufficient to establish a miracle unless the testimony
>   be of such a kind, that its falsehood would be more miraculous, than
>   the fact, which it endeavors to establish." (D. Hume, An Enquiry Concerning the Human Understanding, 1748/ 1777 ed., X 'Of Miracles', para. 87: http://www.gutenberg.org/files/9662/9662-h/9662-h.htm.)

I guess my follow up question would be, what is the epistemology of science?

Also, I am curious as to how the epistemology of science has changed over time. Are there any books/readings on how science's epistemology has changed?

Comment: Evidence is crucial for [science](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/scientific-method/) but science is much more complex that "collecting facts".

Comment: To say testimony can establish a miracle suggests a lack of scepticism to me and a rather unscientific approach to evidence. But sometimes first-person reports are considered to be scientific data, and commonly in scientific consciousness studies.   .  .

Comment: A Good scientist should always keep an open mind but an open mind doesn't give a person the neccessary creativity required to see the right picture/theory in face of evidence. Science can never remove the idea of miracles since it isn't complete or perfect. There will always be room for miracles

Comment: I think there are two questions here, which you would do well to pose separately. (1) The logic of 'Hume on miracles' is a complex topic in its own right. Also it is questionable whether, or how far, Hume's 'wise man' is what we should term 'a scientist' and not something wider and vaguer. (2) The nature of scientific evidence and the changes in our understanding of it over time are huge topics. It may be only my own view  but I think this question needs to be slimmed down (in respect of evidence) and the question about Hume separated off (if you really need to involve Hume here).

Comment: Can you provide the citation for the Hume quote?

Comment: "A [miracle](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/miracles/) (from the Latin mirari, to wonder), at a first and very rough approximation, is an event that is not explicable by natural causes alone", so you can see how miracles cannot be scientifically explained

Comment: Citation added.

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in how science in general has changed, Thomas Kuhn's Structure of Scientific Revolutions is a must read. [The Structure of Scientific Revolutions - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Structure_of_Scientific_Revolutions?cmdf=structure+of+scientific+revolutions). In it, the term "paradigm shift" is coined. Kuhn provides a sort of humbling account of how scientific theories change over time - specifically, how and when countervailing evidence actually causes theories to change (or not). It is one of the most important books to understand the discipline of science, insofar as how it operates in actuality - how people, institutions, information actually operate.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes. Hume is correct. I would recommend Karl Popper on the philosophy of science. He proposed that scientific hypotheses should be falsifiable, not verifiable. This diverges from the previous tendency toward verificationism employing inductive logic. Paradigm shift is another important mechanism of change in science. Authority-backed theories and ad hoc adjustments are eventually swept away in a step change introducing a new, falsifiable hypothesis.